# Represent cruise control system with PID controller as an ode. Issue with Derivative term

Tags: python, ode, odeint, pid-controller

I have been tasked with representing a simple cruise control system with a PID controller as an ordinary differential equation and estimating KP, KI, and KD parameters (I use torchdiffeq library for differentiation and simulation). I know, I can add error to the state to calculate the integral, however, I struggle with the implementation of the derivative. I believe there is a better way to represent the system without the use of 'global' variables.

Here is my current code:

```
    def forward(self, t, x):              
        y, E = x
        dydt = torch.zeros_like(x)
        
        workaround_int = y + y.trunc().detach() - y.detach()
        error = self.Setpoint - workaround_int
        
        inte = E 
        div = (error - self.Error_previous)/self.Dt
        
        pid = self.Params[0]*error + self.Params[1]*inte + self.Params[2]*div
        F_ego = pid
        
        D_ego = self.CdA*(y ** 2)
        
        if y > 0:
            F_net = F_ego - D_ego
        else:
            F_net = F_ego + D_ego

        dydt[0] = F_net/self.M
        dydt[1] = error
        
        self.Error_previous = error
        return dydt
```

If you need any additional information, I am happy to provide!

I have tried to change the system to be of a more correct 'ODE' form by setting the setpoint to 0. This however resulted in an inaccurate system, because of the trunctuated velocity when calculating error. Moreover, it did not solve the issue of having to approximate the derivative term with a finite difference.

I looked at similar problems but they all were related to the higher-order differential equations. I think that technically velocity is of second order but with applied control, it is regarded as first(?).

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the control theory and Laplace transform thus any help would be welcomed.

Comment: It is strange that you compute a force and thus acceleration, but then only have a first-order DE. // Instead of hacking the integration method, which is not reliable, you can also rewrite the DE to avoid derivatives of the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810439/is-there-a-better-way-to-simulate-pid-control.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for your answer, but I think I need more help in understanding it. In the post, you linked you present a system of `y'' + c*y' + k*y = u` where the error is calculated as such `e = yr - y`. In my case, since the system is a cruise control aka `m*y'' + CdA*y'^2 = u` the error is calculated as `e = yr - y'` that's why I saw the majority of resources representing such systems as first-order. When I try to solve the system with `e = yr - y` it produces a trace that is different from the target. Please correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: You should probably work some of these details into the question text. Is `y'` always positive (or zero)? // Yes, with that background the equation is first order, if no position-dependent forces are in play. // The question might be off-topic if it or the answers concentrate on the mathematics, on how to formulate the ODE system so that a standard solver can be applied. I'm not sure if there is an (optimal) control or operations research forum, generically there is scicomp.SE and math.SE. On-topic would be questions on how to correctly use dedicated libraries in matlab or other environments.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The velocity is never negative. There are however cases when the initial velocity (at t0) is 0.  I wanted to know if there is a better way to represent the system at hand for the parameter prediction tasks, as currently, I have to use fixed-step size solvers which are not ideal. Thank you for your help. I will check the forums you have named, but most likely I will continue with the 'hacked ODE' as it is...

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry for nagging, but I wanted to ask you a few questions about the topic. Firstly, would it be better if I used (time - previous_time) instead of the fixed time step? in theory, this would allow me to use more solvers assuming that they don't go 'back' in steps, but I would like to be sure it's a good idea. Secondly, can I call my system a system of first-order DE? If that's not the case could you explain why? Lastly, Is it a good idea to calculate integral error by adding to state or is it better to keep it as 'global' variable. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what you want to implement is `v' + c*sign(v)*v^2 = kp*e + ki*E + kd*e'` where `E' = e` and `e = v_set - v`(?). And the complication is to get `e'`. According to my cited solution, you could set `z = v - kd*e` which would replace the first component of the state. So `z, E = x`. Then `v` would have to be reconstructed from the equation `z = v - kd*err(v)`. In the current case this would be `v = (z+kd*v_set) / (1+kd)`. Then proceed with `z' = -c*abs(v)*v + kp*e + ki*E` etc.