# Issue on Runge Kutta Fehlberg algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, runge-kutta

I have wrote a code for Runge-Kutta 4th order, which works perfectly fine for a system of differential equations:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numba
import time
start_time = time.clock()
 

@numba.jit()
def V(u,t):
    x1,dx1, x2, dx2=u
    ddx1=-w**2 * x1 -b * dx1
    ddx2=-(w+0.5)**2 * x2 -(b+0.1) * dx2
    return np.array([dx1,ddx1,dx2,ddx2])


@numba.jit()
def rk4(f, u0, t0, tf , n):
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, n+1)
    u = np.array((n+1)*[u0])
    h = t[1]-t[0]
    for i in range(n):
        k1 = h * f(u[i], t[i])    
        k2 = h * f(u[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5*h)
        k3 = h * f(u[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5*h)
        k4 = h * f(u[i] + k3, t[i] + h)
        u[i+1] = u[i] + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3) + k4) / 6
    return u, t

u, t  = rk4(V,np.array([0,0.2,0,0.3]) ,0,100, 20000)

print("Execution time:",time.clock() - start_time, "seconds")
x1,dx1,x2,dx2 = u.T
plt.plot(x1,x2)
plt.xlabel('X1')
plt.ylabel('X2')
plt.show()
```

The above code, returns the desired result:
[image]

And thanks to Numba JIT, this code works really fast. However, this method doesn't use adaptive step size and hence, it is not very suitable for a system of stiff differential equations. Runge Kutta Fehlberg method, solves this problem by using a straight forward algorithm. Based on the algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method) I wrote this code which works for **only one** differential equation :

```
import numpy as np

def rkf( f, a, b, x0, tol, hmax, hmin ):

    a2  =   2.500000000000000e-01  #  1/4
    a3  =   3.750000000000000e-01  #  3/8
    a4  =   9.230769230769231e-01  #  12/13
    a5  =   1.000000000000000e+00  #  1
    a6  =   5.000000000000000e-01  #  1/2

    b21 =   2.500000000000000e-01  #  1/4
    b31 =   9.375000000000000e-02  #  3/32
    b32 =   2.812500000000000e-01  #  9/32
    b41 =   8.793809740555303e-01  #  1932/2197
    b42 =  -3.277196176604461e+00  # -7200/2197
    b43 =   3.320892125625853e+00  #  7296/2197
    b51 =   2.032407407407407e+00  #  439/216
    b52 =  -8.000000000000000e+00  # -8
    b53 =   7.173489278752436e+00  #  3680/513
    b54 =  -2.058966861598441e-01  # -845/4104
    b61 =  -2.962962962962963e-01  # -8/27
    b62 =   2.000000000000000e+00  #  2
    b63 =  -1.381676413255361e+00  # -3544/2565
    b64 =   4.529727095516569e-01  #  1859/4104
    b65 =  -2.750000000000000e-01  # -11/40

    r1  =   2.777777777777778e-03  #  1/360
    r3  =  -2.994152046783626e-02  # -128/4275
    r4  =  -2.919989367357789e-02  # -2197/75240
    r5  =   2.000000000000000e-02  #  1/50
    r6  =   3.636363636363636e-02  #  2/55

    c1  =   1.157407407407407e-01  #  25/216
    c3  =   5.489278752436647e-01  #  1408/2565
    c4  =   5.353313840155945e-01  #  2197/4104
    c5  =  -2.000000000000000e-01  # -1/5

    t = a
    x = np.array(x0)
    h = hmax

    T = np.array( [t] )
    X = np.array( [x] )
    
    while t < b:

        if t + h > b:
            h = b - t

        k1 = h * f( x, t )
        k2 = h * f( x + b21 * k1, t + a2 * h )
        k3 = h * f( x + b31 * k1 + b32 * k2, t + a3 * h )
        k4 = h * f( x + b41 * k1 + b42 * k2 + b43 * k3, t + a4 * h )
        k5 = h * f( x + b51 * k1 + b52 * k2 + b53 * k3 + b54 * k4, t + a5 * h )
        k6 = h * f( x + b61 * k1 + b62 * k2 + b63 * k3 + b64 * k4 + b65 * k5, \
                    t + a6 * h )

        r = abs( r1 * k1 + r3 * k3 + r4 * k4 + r5 * k5 + r6 * k6 ) / h
        if len( np.shape( r ) ) > 0:
            r = max( r )
        if r <= tol:
            t = t + h
            x = x + c1 * k1 + c3 * k3 + c4 * k4 + c5 * k5
            T = np.append( T, t )
            X = np.append( X, [x], 0 )

        h = h * min( max( 0.84 * ( tol / r )**0.25, 0.1 ), 4.0 )

        if h > hmax:
            h = hmax
        elif h < hmin:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: Could not converge to the required tolerance %e with minimum stepsize  %e." % (tol,hmin))
            break

    return ( T, X )
```

but I'm struggling to convert it to a function like the first code, where I can input a system of differential equations. The most confusing part for me, is how can I vectorize everything in the second code without messing things up. In other words, I cannot reproduce the first result using the RKF algorithm. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly is the error if you try it with a system? I see no obvious points where that change would break the code. Or is there a problem during run-time? Does it work for simple linear systems?

Comment: Aside from some basic cleanup to make inputs etc fit, this seems fine. I would recommend using np.linalg.norm for computing r.

Comment: @LutzLehmann  It works for only one equation, but I think my problem is that there exists n number  of steps for n equations in each iteration, and I think I should use the minimum of those n steps to apply it to all the calculation.(Imagine a system of two equations, one of them has a very smaller step size than the other. Then I guess I should use the smaller one for both equations) I don't know how to find that minimum step size.

Comment: That you have covered with the lines `if len( np.shape( r ) ) > 0:   r = max( r )`, as that reduces the input to the step size control to a scalar. It is indeed a valid strategy to keep the controller internals separate for components of the system and only take the minimum at the end. When the step sizes become too different, one can also separate the system in fast and slow moving components or influences and integrate them with different time steppings.

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for here: http://people.bu.edu/andasari/courses/numericalpython/python.html . thanks for the help @lutzlehmann

Comment: I see nothing about step size control in that link, both RKF examples are used with fixed step size.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused, isn't RKF supposed to be an  adaptive step size method? Or what this link has done is incomplete? @lutzlehmann

Comment: RKF45 is an embedded Runge-Kutta method, it implements an order 4 method with an order 5 error estimator with one function evaluation more (it works not that well the other way around, extrapolation was optimized in the Dormand-Prince methods). You can drive both the order 4 and the order 5 method as fixed-step methods of that order, which was done in the link, or in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502790/3088138 for the DoPri5 5th order method step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure where your problem lies. Setting the not given parameters to `w=1; b=0.1` and calling, without changing anything

```
T, X = rkf( f=V, a=0, b=100, x0=[0,0.2,0,0.3], tol=1e-6, hmax=1e1, hmin=1e-16 )
```

gives the phase plot

[image]

The step sizes grow as the system slows down as

[image]

which is the expected behavior for an unfiltered step size controller.

Comment: I literally went too deep, and had know I idea the code was already correct... Thanks.